# How to prevent disappear of drop down during on click in Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap in my application. I want to select multiple check boxes in drop down. When i click check box its getting disappear. Please help me to solve this problem.Thanks in advance
This is my code:

```
<div class="btn-group">
        <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><input type="checkbox" /><label>Sunday</label></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" /><label>Monday</label></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" /><label>Tuesday</label></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Here is a way*

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/wCx122K3lu

**JS**:

```
$('input, label').on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="btn-group">
        <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><label><input type="checkbox">Sunday</label></li>
        <li><label><input type="checkbox">Monday</label></li>
        <li><label><input type="checkbox">Tuesday</label></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```